# how do we write a program in c that uses a regular expression to identify whether a stream of characters is grammatical or not.?

Tags: compiler-construction

I am going to design a new compiler.I want to know that how do i use RE to identify the characters.what would be the grammer?How do i implement it?

Comment: A good reference: http://www.amazon.com/Principles-Compiler-Addison-Wesley-information-processing/dp/0201000229/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you shouldn't try to write a compiler using regular expressions; they're the wrong tool for the job.  For a start, they're only useful for identifying strings in [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language); any non-trivial programming language is not regular.

You will probably be best to use [bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) or [Yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) to generate your parser code.

Comment: Actually, regular expressions *are* a valid tool - for tokenization.

Comment: @delnan: true, but it's something of a sledgehammer approach, in most cases.

Comment: Can I identify the String using NFA.if yes,how?

Comment: @sanjoy: No.  An NFA matches regular languages.

Comment: with out using any tools, can you tell me how do i implement it.i had tried to implemented it by yacc.But when i copiler y.tab.c file,i faced a lot of error.what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this website to test your Regular Expressions :
http://rubular.com/

Or you can use this Visual Studio extension to do the same work : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00

Comment: Can I identify the String using NFA.if yes,how?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write a compiler you will need more than regular expressions and should look at tools such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).